# Change type of field in db (table: quote, field: customer_note, current type: varchar, wanted type: text)

Tags: magento2, db-schema

I try to change the type of the field `customer_note` in the `quote` table from `varchar` to `text`. I went the declarative way:

VendorName/Module/etc/db_schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="quote" >
        <column xsi:type="text" name="customer_note" />
    </table>
</schema>
```

Then I try the CLI command

```
bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=VendorName_Module
```

The result:

```
Invalid Document
Element 'column', attribute 'length': The attribute 'length' is not allowed. 
Line: 59
```

The "Line 59" is inside the db_schema.xml in the "Quote" module of the org. magento 2 sources. Is this a known bug and is there any known work around for this?
**Or did I do something wrong?**

Add info: my `module.xml` contains a

```
   <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
   </sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.
There is an official bug report: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26155

The bug is solved in the current 2.4.1 release. But just in the way, that they changed the 'Quote' db-schema.xml.

Well, that is nice, but did why did the official way using the declarative way did not work?